# ¿Como hacer un autocomplete a un input con ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Buenas noches quisiera saber porque no me carga el autocomplete en mi input, agradezco de antemano.

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
    <label for="responsables" class="col-form-label">Responsables</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsables" placeholder="Responsables">
</div>
```

script.js

```
$("#responsables").autocomplete({
            source:function(request,response){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"autocomplete.json",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

autocomplete.json

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nombre":"rojo"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nombre":"Verde"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "nombre":"Azul"
    }
]
```

Comment: Has mirado en consola a ver si te da algún error? Podría ser que no encuentre el json o que tenga algún problema al cargarlo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que el [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) espera un json con los campos **label** y **value**.

> **source**
>
> Type: Array or String or Function( Object request, Function
>   response( Object data ) ) Default: none; must be specified Defines the
>   data to use, must be specified.
>
> Independent of the variant you use, the label is always treated as
>   text. If you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott
>   González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js). The demos all focus on different variations of the source option - look for one that matches your use case, and check out the code.
>
> Multiple types supported:
>
> Array: 
>   An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>
>   The **label property is displayed in the suggestion menu**. The **value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item**.
>     If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if
>     you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>     label.
>
> ...(continúa)
>
> **Fuente:** http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

O bien generas el json de esa forma o usas una función para convertirlo.

En vez de poner:

```
            response(data);
```

Usarías:

```
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.nombre,
                    value: item.id
                }
            }));
```

La función del autocomplete quedaría:

```
$("#responsables").autocomplete({
            source:function(request,response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fcz36",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        search: request.term
                    },                    
                    success:function(data){
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nombre,
                                value: item.id
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Los datos json: http://myjson.com/1fcz36

El código ejecutable: https://jsfiddle.net/k3an9uo4/1/

---

(edito)

Lo mostrado hasta ahora era un ejemplo estático de como configurar el [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) de jQuery UI según la pregunta original.

Para que responda dinamicamente hay que configurar el ajax para que ejecute un script y este devolverá los datos según lo tecleado por el usuario.

Como podemos comprobar en la documentación de [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) en el parámetro **url** indicamos la ruta al script, en **type** configuramos el método a usar (GET o POST) y en **data** los parámetros que deseemos pasar al script, en nuestro caso, al menos, el texto tecleado por el usuario.

```
$("#responsables").autocomplete({
            source:function(request,response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "consulta_ajax.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        search: request.term
                    },                    
                    success:function(data){
                        response($data)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

> Lo más cómodo, si tenemos el control del origen de datos, es que el
>   propio script devuelva el json con los campos **label** y **value** (o
>   solo **label** si no deseamos usar indices) para no complicar el
>   javascript.

**consulta_ajax.php**

```
<?php  
  $mysqli = new mysqli(DBURI,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
  $texto = $_GET['search'];
  $sql = " SELECT id AS value, nombre AS label FROM ciudades WHERE nombre LIKE '%$texto%' "; 
  $result = $mysqli->query($conexion, $sql);

  while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $resultado[]=$myrow;
  }

  echo json_encode($resultado);
  ?>
```

Comment: gracias por tratar de ayudarme, pero al escribir en el input no me filtra la coincidencia me sale todo los datos del autocompletado y cuando selecciono un item del select me muestra el value y no el label