# Chosen Select con miles de opciones

Tags: php, jquery, sql, postgresql, combobox

Tengo una base de datos en postgresql con miles de registros y
para mostrarlos utilizo un campo < select >. 
Necesito que filtren directamente en el select ya que son muchos registros.
Quiero utilizar la libreria Chosen select pero al momento de utilizarla con
tanta cantidad de registros se torna lenta la página.
Habría alguna forma de hacer que mientras escriba vaya cambiando el query, como para ponerle, por ejemplo un limit 100??
Muchas gracias!
Dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo utilizo:

```
<?PHP
include("inc/pgsql.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chosen Select</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.css">
</head>
<body>
    <select name="id_esin" id="id_esin" class="chosen-select">
        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
        <?
        $query_datos = "select id_esin, nom_esin
        from gh0116 where baja = 'n'
        order by nom_esin";
        $con_query=pg_query($pgl_con, $query_datos);
        #Al rededor de 13 mil registros
        $i = 0;
        while($datos = pg_fetch_array($con_query, $i, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$datos[nom_esin]?>"><?=$datos[nom_esin]?></option>
        <?
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <script src="chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para esa cantidad de registros, te convendría usar AJAX y autocomplete. Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247518/como-hacer-un-autocomplete-a-un-input-con-ajax

Comment: Usa [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) con AJAX, podrás emular un elemento SELECT y será más vistozo y fácil de manejar.

Comment: @Pepo Cómo haría para simular el select? Estuve leyendo pero solo me muestra filtros para tablas. Gracias!