# Buscador en vivo, laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Buenas tengo un buscador pero tengo algunas dudas. Os muestro el código primero.

EDITO PREGUNTA PARA VER CON LAS MEJORAS POR QUE SIGUE FALLANDO

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $output = '<div class="result">';
            $products=DB::table('productos')->where('producto','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
            if($products)
                {
                foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                    $output.=
                '<a href="'. route('web.detalle', ['cat' => $product->categoria, 'sub' => $product->subcategoria, 'url' => $product->url]) .'">
                    <div class="row espacioRowBusca">'.
                        '<div class="col-3"><img src='. asset("images/productos/camas/{$product->imagen}") .' alt="" class="imgBuscador"></div>'.
                        '<div class="col-9">
                            <h3>'.$product->marca.'</h3>
                            <h2>'.$product->producto.'</h2>
                            <h5>'.$product->categoria.'/'.$product->subcategoria.'</h5>
                        </div>'.
                    '</div>
                </a>';
                } // end foreach
                } else {
                    $output.= 'No se encontraron resultados';
                } // end if
            $output.='</div>';
            return Response($output);
        }
    }
```

**La ruta**

```
Route::get('/search', "Web@search");
```

**El buscador y donde muestra los resultados**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inputSearch" id="search" name="search" placeholder="¿Que estas buscando?">
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
        data:{'search':$value},
          success:function(data){
            $('#resultados').html(data);
            }
        });
      })
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
  </script>  

<script>
 /* Para quitar resultados buscador y limpiar el input*/
 $(document).on('click', function(e){ 
   if($(e.target) != $("#resultados")) {
       $('#resultados').html('');
       $('#search').val("");
   }
 }); 
</script>
```

Bien lo que necesito es que si no hay resultado muestre un mensaje de no hay resultados.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Ya que estás con jQuery, podrías usar su autocomplete. Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247518/como-hacer-un-autocomplete-a-un-input-con-ajax

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta @Triby , perdona mi ignorancia pero de que me sirve el autocomplete para que si hago clic fuera ese div se cierre y si no hay resultados me muestre un aviso en ese mismo div?

Comment: Revísalo mientras te sugiero una respuesta.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @Triby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en lugar de usar el *autocomplete* de jQuery prefieres seguir con lo que ya tienes, creo que lo primero es mover `return Response($output);` una llave abajo, fuera del `if`, para garantizar que siempre devuelves algo y agrega un evento *onclick* a los enlaces:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output = '<div class="result">';
        $products=DB::table('productos')->where('producto','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
        // Verificar que hay resultados para mostrar
        if(count($products) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                $output.=
        '<a href="" onclick="linkBusca(this);">
            <div class="row espacioRowBusca">'.
                '<div class="col-3"><img src='. asset("images/productos/camas/{$product->imagen}") .' alt="" class="imgBuscador"></div>'.
                '<div class="col-9">
                    <h3>'.$product->marca.'</h3>
                    <h2>'.$product->producto.'</h2>
                    <h5>'.$product->categoria.'/'.$product->subcategoria.'</h5>
                </div>'.
            '</div>
        </a>';
            } // end foreach
        } else {
            $output .= 'No se encontraron resultados';
        } // end if
        $output.='</div>';
        return Response($output);
    }
}
```

Luego, en Javascript, agrega la función para cerrar el div luego de hacer clic en un enlace:

```
<script>
function linkBusca(item) {
    // Puedes usar item para buscar contenido del enlace en que se hizo clic
    // Limpia el contenido del div de resultados
    $('#resultados').html();
}
// Eliminar resultados si se hace clic fuera
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    // Si el clic es fuera de resultados
    if($(e.target) != $("#resultados")) {
        // Limpia el contenido del div de resultados
        $('#resultados').html('');
    }
};
</script>
```

Una de las ventajas de usar *autocomplete* es que PHP devuelve solo un arreglo con resultados y los formateas en el navegador, reduciendo la transferencia de datos y, por supuesto, mejorando el rendimiento.

Respecto al comportamiento, es más fácil controlar que se cierren los resultados al hacer clic en un enlace o, incluso, al hacer clic en otra parte de la página.

Comment: Hola @Triby . Lo de no se encontraron resultados no lo muestra, sale el div vacio. Y respecto a  lo de que se cierren los resultados, justo quiero lo que dices, que al hacer clic en un enlace o en otra parte se cierra, pero no se como utilizar lo que me dices aquí: `function linkBusca(item) .....`

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como lo tienes ahora, para saber por qué no muestra el mensaje. El código Javascript solo colócalo debajo del que tienes para ejecutar la llamada AJAX.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta @Triby

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, haciendo que el mensaje "No se encontraron resultados" quede dentro del div y agregué el javascript para cerrar cuando se hace clic fuera de la lista.

Comment: Hola @Triby me sigue sin funcionar, se queda el div sin nada y no muestra lo de `no se encontraron resultados` y lo de hacer clic fuera tampoco funciona, que puede ser..?

Comment: Revisa la consola, por ahí debe haber algún error. También haz un `console.log(data);` para ver si estás recibiendo el mensaje.

Comment: No me sale ningún error en la consola, ya probe el console.log y se queda el div vacio

Comment: Entonces PHP no está devolviendo el mensaje

Comment: La consola muestra bien a través del `console.log` los resultados que muestra y luego como se queda vacio en lugar de poner no hay resultados

Comment: Por eso, PHP no está devolviendo el mensaje.

Comment: Que te parece si lo hago así? @Triby . `if($(e.target) != $("#resultados")) { $("#resultados").empty(); $('#search').val(""); } . Hago empty en el div y vacio el input`

Comment: Solo limpia resultados, no el input, eso sería muy invasivo, es el usuario quien debe tener control de lo que teclea, pero sí, `empty()` puede ser la solución. De hecho, fue mi error, porque al tener `$("#resultados").html();` _devuelve_ el contenido, faltaban comillas para limpiar: `$("#resultados").html('');`

Comment: Ya lo cambie por lo tuyo! pero es correcto hacerlo así? y por otro lado @Triby lo de mostrar que no hay resultados sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Sí, es correcto. Ahora solo falta ver porqué PHP no devuelve el mensaje, por favor actualiza la pregunta para ver cómo quedó al final.

Comment: Pregunta actualizada @Triby

Comment: Probé el código en mi PC y funciona correctamente. Agrega `error:function(peticion, estado, error) { console.log(estado, error); }` para ver si algo está fallando en la petición.

Comment: Perdona donde situo ese código @Triby

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109171/discussion-between-triby-and-miguel).