# Como hacer un buscador en tiempo real y mandarle un id dinámico?

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos, buscador

bueno estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en tiempo pero pretendo meter la tabla donde estará mi input dentro de un foreach para que de esta manera dependiendo de la info que hay en mi base de datos se genere un buscador por dato que contenga mi consulta, por esta razón es que le estoy asignando un id dinámico.

Una disculpa por si cometí algún error, soy nuevo en esto pero estoy aprendiendo.

Mi función

```js
//Aqui no tengo la menor idea de como pasar mi id dinamico y ponerlo aqui para que me haga la busqueda dependiendo del id que le toque.
    $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#po").keyup(function(){
                  var parametros="po="+$(this).val()
                  $.ajax({
                        data:  parametros,
                      url:   'editar_envio.php',
                      type:  'post',
                        beforeSend: function () { },
                        success:  function (response) {                 
                            $(".divCarga").html(response);
                      },
                      error:function(){
                           alert("error")
                        }
                   });
             })
    })
```

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 90%">
                <tr>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">POs:&nbsp;
//Aqui es donde le pongo un id dinamico al id de mi input
<input id="po-<?php echo $dato_captura['id_captura']; ?>" size="30" name="po" type="text" placeholder="Search"></th>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="background-color: #5499c7;">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th style="background-color: black;">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="background-color: black; color: white;">Lote</th>
                  <th style="background-color: black; color: white;">Estilo</th>
                  <th style="background-color: black; color: white;">Color</th>
                  <th style="background-color: black; color: white;">Descripcion</th>
                  <th style="background-color: black; color: white;">Genero</th>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                  <td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;" width="25%"></td>
                  <td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;" colspan="5" >
                  <select class="form-control divCarga" name="select_pos" id="select_pos-<?php echo $dato_captura['id_captura']; ?>">
                    <option disabled selected><?php echo $dato_captura['lote'].",".$dato_captura['estilo'].",".$dato_captura['color'].",".$dato_captura['descripcion'].",".$dato_captura['genero']; ?></option>
                  </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>



<?php

if($_POST['po']){
               
              ?>
              <option disabled selected>Selected</option>
              <?php
              $cons_po = $obj->consultar("SELECT * FROM t_wip WHERE po_lot LIKE '%".$_POST['po']."%'");
              foreach ($cons_po as $key){ 
              ?>
              
              <option value="<?php echo $key['id_wip']; ?>"><?php echo $key['po_lot'].",".$key['style'].",".$key['color'].",".$key['description'].",".$key['gender']; ?></option>
              <?php
              }
              }
?>
```

Comment: Hacer tantas peticiones AJAX al servidor lo sobrecargaría haciendo que eventualmente se caiga, te recomiendo usar [WebSockets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Saludos.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/363888/54039), probablemente te pueda servir.